# rails 3: is there a way to put a gem's config params in environment.rb instead of foo.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, yaml

My rails app uses a gem that requires some config params to be specified in foo.yml:

```
development:
  username: MyDevUserName
  password: MyDevPassword
production:
  username: MyPRODUserName
  password: MyPRODPassword
```

I dont want the password in my source code and want to do something like:

```
development:
  username: <%= ENV['THE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['THE_PASSWORD'] %>
production:
  username: <%= ENV['THE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['THE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

However, for some reason that <%= ENV['XXX'] %> does work in my Settings.yml file, but does not work in my foo.yml file (I'm guessing however the foo gem loads the .yml file it does not allow interpretation).

So...

I'm wondering if Ruby/Rails has a general-purpose way to specify the variables in environment.rb instead of a foo.yml file?

Can i for example have an empty foo.yml file and add the following to **environment.rb**:

```
Foo::_something_._somethingelse =
{
  :username => ENV['THE_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['THE_PASSWORD']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT: Since you are on Heroku...*

Heroku is a different story. Your use of ENV may be conflicting with some functionality built into Heroku for handling config vars such as the ones you are working with. You need (drumroll, please)... **CONFIG VARS**. See [this page in the Heroku Dev Center](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for information on how to set config vars in your Heroku deployment, how to access them from your app, and how to make it all work locally as well.

*EDIT: Below is the original answer, still applicable in the general (non-heroku) case*

Even if you put it in environment.rb, it will still be in your source code.

The correct way to do this is to ignore the foo.yml file in your version control (for instance, in git you would add the file to the .gitignore file). That way, you have the file locally where you need it, but it never gets committed to your repository, so your creds aren't exposed. On your deployment server, you will have to manually create that file as well, since when you deploy from source code the deployment won't have it.

If you are using capistrano for deployment, a common approach would be to put the file in [app]/shared/config/foo.yml, then add a deployment task to softlink from [sharedpath] into [releasepath]. Such a task in capistrano might look like this:

```
task :after_update_code do
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/foo.yml #{release_path}/config/foo.yml"
end
```

Comment: thanks for that info, tho I'm hoping there's a way to be able to load automatically from the ENV variables since we're on Heroku and that capability is easy to deploy.

Comment: @jpwynn I've updated my answer with Heroku-specific guidance.